# Can I add members to an existing type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Looking at the [definition file for the commander project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/commander/index.d.ts), you can see this in one of the interfaces it uses:

```
interface IExportedCommand extends ICommand {
    Command: commander.ICommandStatic;
    Option: commander.IOptionStatic;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

The catch-all `[key: string]: any;` is nice, but I'm curious to see if I could make that a little nicer by augmenting the type within my own files with specifically named members.

Unfortunately, because of the namespacing and module behaviour (something I'm really still only something like 85% confident with), I can't quite come up with the right incantation.

I feel like somehow through declaration merging, I can get what I want to add members to that interface.  Or maybe it's not possible and I just can't track down that fact...

Answer (score -1):

You can simple add to your file

```
interface IExportedCommand {
    myOption: string;
}
```

If you want to use this extends in multiple files I recommed you to add it into separated file. If your IDE don't load it automaticaly force it by reference comment in header.

```
/// <reference path="path/to/your/file.ts" />
```

Comment: Pretty certain you shouldn't be using `///` references in TS anymore.